# No returns for Parse query

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to pull locations near a user via Parse for tableview, except I only get either a white screen or an empty table.

**Edited:** I neglected to add the call for location before query near geopoint is submitted. In testing, I found that location was determined under 'geoPontForCurrentLocationInBackground'. However, once the geopoint is established and the query is submitted, the user location returns no latitude or longitude within the query. Moreover, the query doesn't return any objects and I'm not sure why:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "User")

     PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (userLocation: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

        }
    }

    let point: PFGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: self.userLoc.latitude, longitude: self.userLoc.longitude)
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: point, withinMiles: 50.0)
    query.limit = 10
    return query
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Shops
    if let object = object {
        if let shopName = object.valueForKey("shopName") as? String {
        cell.shopList.text = shopName
   }
   }
    return cell as Shops
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that Parse treats the User class as a **special** class. You may have difficulty querying User class if you treat it as if it was a Custom Class.

The correct and tested way to do this is to the the query function of **PFUser**.

```
var query = PFUser.query()
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I tried omitting the class name with an empty argument, but it also returned no objects.

Comment: Thats not what I provided.

Comment: try using the query func of PFUser not PFQuery

Comment: Just got done incorporating your and Adam's suggestions. Great suggestion. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up the query, but never actually executing it. [Per the Parse documents](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo/iOS), you need to add:

```
// Final list of objects
queryResults = query.findObjects()
```

Before your `queryForTable()` `return` statement in order to get the query objects.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I just tested it with 'query.findObjects', but it's still not loading any objects. I tried adding 'var queryResults= NSString()' as the first line after the method is established and then 'queryResults = query.findObjects()' as recommended. Also ran it with 'query.findObjects()'. (I should add that I'm a newbie in Swift and Parse; please pardon my ignorance.)

Comment: You'll want to incorporate @ericgu's suggestion of the custom User class as well as making sure you're returning the `queryResults` variable.

Comment: Thank you, Adam!! (Too bad I can't check both answers as it was the combo. If I could, I would upvote your response.)